# Preperiod and Period of the nim-sequence of Octal Games .17 and .117

Tags: sequences-and-series, periodic-functions, combinatorial-game-theory

This refers to a type of impartial game defined as octal games by Berlekamp, Guy and Conway in the first edition of the Winning Ways books.

I noticed that the nim-sequences of $.17$ and $.117$ (first cousin of $.051$) both have a preperiod of $p-1$ for their period $p$ ($p=34$ and $p=48$).

This seems interesting given they have nearly a full cycle before the periodicity starts. Also fairly unusual? I haven't noticed it in other octal games. I assume that both having this property is due to the similarities in the rules of the games?

I was wondering if anyone was able to conjecture why they have preperiod $p-1$ based on the rules of the games? Or is there a reason in general that ultimately periodic sequences might be likely to have preperiod $p-1$?

Perhaps there is nothing interesting to notice?

Comment: For $.134$ the pre-period is $p-2$. For $.171$ it's $p+1$. For $.226$ it's $p+16$. (I'm just reading off of [Flammenkamp's list](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/easy_octal.txt).)
I don't think "nearly a full cycle before the periodicity starts" is all that surprising, and don't imagine $p-1$ has particular significance, though I'd be willing to be convinced.

Comment: Fair enough, I suspected that would probably be the case. Thank you anyway